# How to Enable Silent Reloading in TexStudio?

Tags: texstudio, warnings

I constantly receive the following message, whenever I edit a tex file, using TeXstudio 3.0.1:

> was changed outside of TeXstudio. Reload from disk?
>
> Notes:
>
> - Reloading overwrites the editor content with the file from disk. This cannot be undone.
> - You can permanently enable silent reloading in the options.

I'm saving my tex files on a cloud, which has worked well in the past, and am only working on it from one machine at the moment. This message pops up every time I compile something now and is quite annoying.

What bothers me is that it suggests silent reloading but thi is nowhere to be found in the options menu. Does anyone have any idea how one can stop this behaviour?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I also occasionally get the following warning:

> ~ has been modified by another application.
> Press "Save" to overwrite the file on disk
> Press "Reset" to reload the file from disk.
> Press "Diff" to show differences in the editor.
> Press "Ignore" to ignore this warning.

Again, I see where this comes from (probably the fact that I save the file on a cloud) but it would be good to be able to disable this.

Comment: Which cloud service and OS are you using?  I'm surprised that the cloud client is modifying the file.  What does "Diff" show as being the difference?

Comment: I use the iCloud and MacOS 11.0.1 (20B29). I can't quite replicate the second warning as it seems to occur more or less randomly when I edited the file (which is also strange). But there shouldn't really be a difference as I am only editing on one machine at the moment.

Comment: I've got the warning again now: As diffs it only shows what I edited in the tex file before building the PDF again. So it seems to think that the edit has come from a different machine, but it hasn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is based on the Windows version.

[optional step] You can find any option by checking `Show Advanced Options`

[image]

By typing `reload` in the field below of `(option filter)`, and you will find it is in `Adv. Editor`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, for Mac it's Texstudio --> Preference and then typing reload into the option filter search field. I've found the option there and ticked this. Let's hope that this did the trick. Needless to say, should anyone who's involved in texstudio updates read this: The hint "You can permanently enable silent reloading in the options." given in one of the warnings doesn't seem to be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. TeXstudio 3.0.4 is installed on Linux (Fedora 33) using `dnf`. The folder containing the .tex file is synchronized using the free **OneDrive** client for Linux https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive Each time I save the file in TeXstudio, a dialog window appears, warning that the file was changed outside TeXstudio

This never happens with .tex files in folders, which are synchronized using the official **Dropbox** client for Linux.

Using `stat` command, I checked the difference between properties of a freshly saved .tex file before and after the synchronization is enabled.

- In the case of ***OneDrive***, only *access time* has changed
- In the case of ***Dropbox***, both *access time* and *change time* have changed.

I wonder what does OneDrive client do with the file, which makes TeXstudio think that the file has changed. Also, the file in OneDrive folder has attributes 600, while the file in Dropbox folder has attributes 644 - can it be relevant to the issue?